# Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Is it possible to execute PowerShell script inside c# the same way PowerShell is able to run vb/macro script inside PowerShell like so:

```ps
$script = @' (vb script) '
$excel.Run('Script', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...)
```

Comment: Yes, but it's rarely the best option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen as a duplicate of this stackoverflow discussion(s)

[Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments)

[To call a powershell script file (example.ps1) from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195392/to-call-a-powershell-script-file-example-ps1-from-c-sharp)

```
Try creating scriptfile as a separate command:

Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);

then you can add parameters with

CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key","value");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

and finally

pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

Here is the complete, edited code:

RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

//Here's how you add a new script with arguments
Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key","value");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

// Execute PowerShell script
results = pipeline.Invoke();
```