# How to call power shell script file by passing attributes in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

How to call power shell script file by passing attributes in c#.
I'm using below code to call ps1 file by passing inputs but getting error near invoke.
 error message:

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The term
>   'Get-Childitem C:\samplemm.ps1' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.'

```
namespace SCOMWebAPI.Services
{
    public class MaintennceModeService
    {
        private static IEnumerable<PSObject> results;

        internal static string post(MaintenanceMode value)
        {
            // create Powershell runspace

            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();

            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
            Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Childitem C:\\samplemm.ps1");
            CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("mgmtserver", "NodeName");
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

            pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            // Execute PowerShell script
            results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            // convert the script result into a single string

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
              stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type the command `Get-ChildItem C:\\samplemm.ps1` into powershell, you are actually binding the text `C:\\samplemm.ps1` to the default parameter `Path`.

The problem with your code is that you have included the first parameter as part of the command name. Simply separate it out.

Instead of

```
Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Childitem C:\\samplemm.ps1");
```

Separate out the parameter:

```
Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Childitem");
CommandParameter pathParameter = new CommandParameter("Path", "C:\\samplemm.ps1");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(pathParameter);
```

Comment: actually I need to pass input variables to powershell script and capture the return from powershell script and convert to json format.

Comment: @Jack - this information is not mentioned in your question.  Your question talks only about the error.  As per that this answer seems to be appropriate.  You will have to add details in question on what kind of json you want and exactly what are you wanting to accomplish ?.

Comment: @Jack - Rather than adding details into your question, post a new, different question.

Comment: Thanks guys I am able fix with the solution you provided